Remote Debugging with build updates
I am using Visual Studio 2022 remote debugger. It works well but every time I want to change the code, I need to build again and copy the new DLLs to the remote machine.
Is there a way to automate the 'publishing' of the build output to the remote machine also? I.e. whenever I am building, the remote DLLs will be also be updated.
I tried using a shared folder but it is not an option because of company restrictions and IT Security reasons.
